# Cannot Create a User Account on Mac OS X 10.5.8 Leopard

Tags: macos, leopard, accounts

I am having trouble with iMac running OS X 10.5.8. I used to be all the time in the administrator account (mine) but I forgot my password so I did the reboot thing. Now it sends me to the Create Account (Apple video intro, select a language, and everything) and when I'm done creating the account it sends me again to the start. What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to recover data from the original account?

Comment: @ArchonOSX no, I don't have any important information, I'd reset the Mac but I don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 2):

You will need an original OS X install disc for a computer that old if you can't get it to start up and get to the desktop.

Reinstall the original OS by following a guide such as [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Mac+OS+X+10.5+Leopard/751). Re-initialize the disc and create a new administrator account.

Then you could use "Software Update" that is built-in to the OS, to update to a newer version of the OS if you like.

Good Luck!